# how checking if there is a value in a heapq

Tags: python, graph, heap-memory, heapsort

I am working heapq package in order to work with graphs.

Let's suppose a list " heap ", filed by 2 tuples a and b representing ( distance, node )

```
import heapq

heap = []
a = (321,4)
b = (258,3)
heapq.heappush(heap,a)
heapq.heappush(heap,b)
```

Is there any way to check if node 4 is in the heap list ? and if yes, how can I get its distance ?

Comment: Check if 4 is in a: `4 in a`

Comment: What if both the tuples have same nodes? How do you intend to get the distance then?

Comment: Use a dict for distances lookup and put only nodes in `heap`.

Comment: Hiii, a and b are just two variables, I could write that heapq.heappush(heap,(321, 4)).  The type of my nodes are integer so the heap is automaticly sorted in function of nodes and not the distance. May I missunderstood something ? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `any`:

```
import heapq

heap = []
a = (321,4)
b = (258,3)
heapq.heappush(heap,a)
heapq.heappush(heap,b)
node = 4
if any(node in d for d in heap):
     print("The Distance of the node {} is {}".format(node, [x[0] for x in heap if x[1] == node]))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
The Distance of the node 4 is [321]
```

**OR**:

```
print("The Distance of the node {} is {}".format(node, str([x[0] for x in heap if x[1] == node]).strip("[]")))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
The Distance of the node 4 is 321
```

Comment: hiii and thank you DirtyBit, is it the only way to use for loop ?

Comment: @harry this is using `list comprehension` which is the preferred way. Did it solve your problem?